# Closing kinematic loop with trac_ik

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, trac-ik, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello List,

Creating simulation of a rower in a boat using ros, gazebo and trac_ik.
There are three kinematic loops in the robot's description. This cannot be described in URDF, so they should be closed when generating the SDF from it.
I use ik_fast to find the correct joint values for this. I created stubs on both sides of the, still, broken arm's, and ask trac_ik how to close them.

The project can be found om my [github page](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/Rowing).
The code resides in the [boot3_description](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/Rowing/tree/master/boot3_description) directory.
Please see this [screenshot](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/Rowing/blob/master/rviz_broken_arm.png) of the rower in rviz.
The loop with the left arm is closed, but the right arm not yet.
Also note the stub-links that have to be placed on top of each other.

I create a program [ik_1.py](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/Rowing/blob/master/boot3_description/closechains/ik_1.py) that uses the `joint state controller` and `trac_ik` to calculate the correct values of the arm joints to close the loop.
The new initial joint values are written in [param.xacro](https://github.com/SietseAchterop/Rowing/blob/master/boot3_description/config/param.xacro) to be used later.

Now my question.
The program works perfectly when closing the left arm, but does NOT yield the proper values for the right arm.
trac_ik finds a solution, but when the new values are used the right arm is not connected.

I can't find any difference in the two chains, apart of course of the different values to get another arm.
How can trac_ik find a solution that is clearly wrong?

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

**UPDATE:**  I was confused, I use trac_ik, not ik_fast.

Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317928/closing-kinematic-loop-with-trac_ik/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2019-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-07**:
You keep referring to `ik_fast`, but in your script I only see `trac_ik`.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2019-03-07**:
Oops, you are right. Thanks, Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question.

There where some differences in the arms in orientation, and how axes where set, that got me confused.
That is now corrected, and using the `ik_1.py` program I can now close the kinematic loops.

The use case is that, during experiments I need to change the model slightly, larger rower,  shorter oars etc.
After that the kinematic loops are broken and should be closed again.

Sorry for the confusion.

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2019-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0